# ReactJS: Rendering a list of request components does not display any information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code:

requests.data.js:

```
export default {
    requests: [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "timestamp": Date.now(),
            "description": "Need help with ordering",
            "status": "Assistance Requested"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I have the following Request component.

request.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changeRequest } from '../../redux/requests/requests.actions';
import './request.styles.scss';

class Request extends Component {

    handleClick = (id, status) => {
        this.props.changeRequest(id, status);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="request-box">
                <div className="request-details">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Table {this.props.id}, {this.props.timestamp}</h1>
                        <h2>{this.props.description}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="status-button">
                        <button type="button" className="request-button" onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.id, this.props.status)}>{this.props.status}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )    
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        requests: state.requests.requests
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeRequest: (id, status) => { dispatch(changeRequest(id, status)) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Request);
```

This component is displayed in the following page.

requests.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Request from '../../components/request/request.component';
import './requests.styles.scss';

class RequestListPage extends Component {

    render() {
        const { requests } = this.props;
        const requestList = requests.length ? (
            requests.map(request => {
                return(
                    <Request request={request} key={request.id}/>
                )
            })
        ) : (
            <div>No requests yet.</div>
        )

        return (
            <div className="requests-page">
                <h1>Requests</h1>
                <div className="requests-container">
                    <div className="request-list">
                        {requestList}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        requests: state.requests.requests
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RequestListPage);
```

In the above code, the RequestListPage component maps each request object from the state to a Request component, so that a Request component is concerned about a single Request and not a list.

However, when I run my application, I get the following:

[image]

The data in the Request component is not getting displayed. I am not sure why this is occurring. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending each request as

```
<Request request={request} key={request.id}/>
```

so you should use it as

```
<h2>{this.props.request.description}</h2>
```

You can also spread the request object like

```
<Request {...request} key={request.id}/>
```

to use them directly(`this.props.description`) as you were using.

or you can also destructure them inside the Request component if you like

```
const { description, status, id, timestamp } = this.props.request;
```

and use them like

`<h2>{description}</h2>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were having is that the properties of the request in the Request component were in this.props.request rather than this.props directly. This is because you were creating the elements using: `<Request request={request} key={request.id}/>` rather than `<Request {...request} key={request.id}/>`

```
class Request extends Component {

    handleClick = (id, status) => {
        this.props.changeRequest(id, status);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="request-box">
                <div className="request-details">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Table {this.request.props.id}, {this.props.request.timestamp}</h1>
                        <h2>{this.props.request.description}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="status-button">
                        <button type="button" className="request-button" onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.request.id, this.props.status)}>{this.props.request.status}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )    
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        requests: state.requests.requests
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeRequest: (id, status) => { dispatch(changeRequest(id, status)) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to spread in the `request` object's properties since in `Request` you access them as `this.props.XXX` versus `this.props.request.XXX`.

```
<Request {...request} key={request.id}/>
```

Defining required propTypes would have caught this for you.